# Center Align CheckBox in Options Menu

Tags: java, android, kotlin, menu, android-optionsmenu

Is it possible to center align CheckBox in Options Menu? As you can see below, the checkbox is not aligned with submenuarrow.
[image]

Comment: please share your xml layout

Comment: There's no XML it's just options menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:actionLayout="@[package:]layout/layout_resource_name"` attribute. With this attribute, you can design your menu like normal layout. Try `app:actionLayout` if `android:actionLayout` not work

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding checkable parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/show_artists_item"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Show Album Artists"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```